# Lua Proportional Matrix Enlargement with Stretched Values

Tags: matrix, lua

I am currently working in a game spell system and I want to know if anyone knows a simple way to enlarge a matrix and also its values, almost like an image stretch.

I am using 2D matrices to represent the spell affected areas, so the below matrix represent the starting spell effect point and its effect area.

Example:

```
local area = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
              {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
              {1, 1, 3, 1, 1},
              {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
              {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Where: 
    3: Origin point (where the spell was cast) 
    1: Affected area relative to the origin point.

Taking this in consideration, I would like to develop a function to enlarge the matrix.

```
function matrix.enlarge(mtx, row, col) ... end
```

The abstraction and result of the following function taking the shown example of an area would be something like following:

```
local enlarged_matrix = matrix.enlarge(area, 2, 2)
matrix.print(enlarged_matrix)

--output
--local area = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
--              {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
--              {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
--              {1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1},
--              {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
--              {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
--              {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: I think it depends why you are enlarging the matrix: is it to represent the spell extending further away from caster (like ripple effect when a pebble hits water), or is it because you need more detail (interpolation)? Also, how many times per second will this enlargement occur?

Comment: Hello Scholliii, thank you very much for your time.
I am enlarging the matrix to make the spell effect area bigger, it will have many uses for me such as to animate it growing without having to programmatically create like 5 areas in sequence and execute them in different delays.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

1. brute force: create new matrix, copy old into it:

   ```
   function matrix.enlarge(area, horiz, vert)
       local vertNow = #vert
       local horizNow = #horiz
       local newVert = vertNow + vert
       local newHoriz = horizNow + horiz
       -- create table of zeros
       local newMatrix = {}
       for i=1,newVert do
           tt = {}
           newMatrix[i] = tt
           for j=1,newHoriz do
               if i > vert/2 and i < vertNow + vert/2 and j > horiz/2 and j < horizNow + horiz/2 then
                   tt[j] = area[i][j]
               else
                   tt[j] = 0
               end
           end
       end
   end
   ```
2. use formula: you have circular symmetry so just need radius, no need to store the value:

   ```
   function distance(i,j) 
        return math.sqrt(i*i+j*j)
   end
   local dissip = 2 -- at a distance of "2", spell is e^(-0.5) of center
   function getSpellStrength(dist) -- gaussian
        return 3*math.exp(-math.pow(dist/dissip, 2))
   end
   val = getSpellStrength(distance(i,j))
   ```

   If the actual computation of spell strength is heavy, and spread doesn't change often (say only when experience increases by a certain delta), then option 1 better. If spread changes quickly (say every time frame while spell taking effect), and spell strength as simple as gaussian, then option 2 better. For in-between cases it depends you'll have to try both. But #2 is simpler so I would favor it unless you can show that it is a performance bottleneck.

   Also, the formula (option 2) is trivial to apply regardless of shape of room/area. If an enemy is at i1,j1, and caster at i2,j2, you can know immediately the spell strength at i1,j1 via distance(i1-i2,j1-j2), regardless of shape of room. You can also fairly easily combine effects of multiple spells, like a resistence spell by enemy (same distance formula).

   If you really have to use matrix, and it must work for any shape, then probably this is best option:
3. scale the old matrix to a new matrix:

   ```
   function enlarge(area, deltaX, deltaY)
       sizeX = #(area[1])
       sizeY = #area -- number of rows
       scaleX = (sizeX + deltaX)/sizeX 
       scaleX = (sizeY + deltaY)/sizeY
       newArea = {}
       for iY=1, sizeY do
           newRow = {}
           newArea[iY] = newRow
           fromY = round(iY/scaleY)
           for jX=1, sizeX do
               fromX = round(jX/scaleX)
               if fromY < 1 or fromX < 1 or fromY > sizeY or fromX > sizeX then 
                   val = 0
               else
                   val = area[fromY][fromX]
               end
               newRow[jX] = val
           end
       end
       return newArea
   end
   ```

   Here, you're basically creating a scaled version of the original (interpolation). WARNING: Not debugged, so you will have to massage this a bit (like there might be +-1 missing in a few places, you should declare your vars local, etc). And round() would be something like

   ```
   function round(x)
       return math.floor(num + 0.5)
   end
   ```

   But hopefully you can do the rest of the work :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it right away.. this will work if the matrix is not symmetrical?

Sorry, but I forgot to mention but some areas may be in wave format and other exceptional formats... like waves, beams, crosses, etc..

Comment: Sorry but I haven't managed to make it work even with circular areas.. it appears that something is wrong. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Actually none.. but it might be me just beeing a noob.
For the second option I didn't quite understand how it would be used.. again, I have no experience on this kind of matrix low level operations.

Comment: I extended my answer to cover the non-circular case. I would stick with option 2 as explained. Option 2 does not use matrices, this way you don't need matrix. If you post what you tried (extend your question), might be able to help. BTW you can gain reputation points by suggesting edits to other questions (you can 2 points for every edit accepted) to cleanup typos etc, useful to all readers and this way you can vote.

Comment: Oh, I see.. but in my case I am obliged to have a resulting matrix in order to pass it to the execution function. The execution function is something like this: executeInArea(playerPosition, area, func, funcArgs) I did not know about the points, thank you very much for the  information, it is very useful.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you re-create an area with larger size? For example if you have a 3x3 cross area, and you want a 5x5 cross area, why not just create a new 5x5 area, instead of enlarging the 3x3?

Comment: I could do that but I would need to do it manually and it would lost it's purpose. My main goal of doing this at the moment is to enlarge areas in a buff system. There are dozens of spells with different areas and if the buff is used with the spell, it will make the area effect area larger. Writting dozens of magnified areas manually would not be viable as the current area size and shapes would be unkown. Thank you very much for your time, I deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will help some people to contribute to the community and vote for your answer!!! Great job!